# TSQL Distinct in Select Statement with Joins

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that is providing the correct data to me but if there are multiple records in the `tuitionSubmission` table for the same `empID`, it shows duplicate results (as expected).

I am trying to use a distinct selector on this query on `A.[empID]`

Below is my Query:

`SELECT A.[empID],
               A.[id],
               A.[empGradDate],
               A.[status],
               A.[reimbursementDate],
               A.[firstName],
               A.[lastName],
               A.[businessTitle] AS department,
               B.[SupEmpID],
               B.[ntid] AS empNTID,
               B.[GeoLocationDesc] AS location,
               C.[FirstName] + ' ' + C.[LastName] AS supervisor,
               C.[ntid] AS supNTID,
               C.[SupEmpID],
               D.[FirstName] + ' ' + D.[LastName] AS manager,
               D.[ntid] AS managerNTID
        FROM   tuitionSubmissions AS A
               INNER JOIN
               empTable AS B
               ON A.[empID] = B.[EmpID]
               INNER JOIN
               empTable AS C
               ON C.[empID] = B.[SupEmpID]
               INNER JOIN
               empTable AS D
               ON D.[empID] = C.[SupEmpID]
        WHERE

            B.[EmpID]= COALESCE(@ntid, B.[EmpID]) OR
            B.[SupEmpID]= COALESCE(@supervisor, B.[SupEmpID]) OR
            C.[SupEmpID]= COALESCE(@manager, C.[SupEmpID]) OR
            A.[EmpID]= COALESCE(@empName, C.[EmpID]) OR
            B.[GeoLocationDesc]= COALESCE(@theLocation, B.[GeoLocationDesc]) OR
            B.[SiloDesc]= COALESCE(@department, B.[SiloDesc])
        FOR    XML PATH ('details'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');`

The table tuitionSubmissions can contain multiple records for the same user (same empID) but I only want to show one of them

Comment: "I only want to show one of them" which one?

Comment: any one, its the same user its finding they just happened to have multiple submissions in the tuitionSubmissions table. All im doing is throwing a button next to it containing their ID number to then pull all their records.

Comment: Can you add examples of the output you are seeing and the output you expect to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811687/tsql-distinct-in-select-statement-with-joins#comment36630317_23811687):

> "I only want to show one of them" which one?–  usr

is extremely important, because that's the crux of the issue. If you have duplicates, you need some rule to determine which of two duplicates is correct. If the duplicate rows are 100% identical, then you're missing a Primary Key. (*And now you see why they're so important*.)

Even if all you do is add a `RowId IDENTITY` column so that you know which of the duplicates was more recently added, this will go a long way to making your life easier. I'd also suggest you go about removing your duplicates, they're not contributing any information, and simply wasting space. Here's a question asking [how to remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18932/224704) which should help.

However, if you want to hang on to the duplicates, you can complicate your query by removing them "on the fly".

```
;WITH UniqueSubs AS (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                [id], [empGradDate], [status], [reimbursementDate],
                [firstName], [lastName], [businessTitle], [EmpID]
        FROM    tuitionSubmissions
      )
SELECT  A.[empID],
/*      ... And the rest of your query as is.
        ... Just substitute tuitionSubmissions with UniqueSubs.
*/
```

However, since you have an `id` column, perhaps you already have that IDENTITY column I mentioned earlier. This can be used as a "uniqueifier" to get the most recent version of `tuitionSubmissions` per `EmpID` as follows:

```
;WITH RecentSubs AS (
        SELECT  EmpID, MAX(id) AS MaxID
        FROM    tuitionSubmissions
      ),
      UniqueSubs AS (
        SELECT  ts.*
        FROM    RecentSubs rs
                INNER JOIN tuitionSubmissions ts ON
                    ts.id = rs.id
                /*Prev join condition should suffice, but add if needed*/
                --AND ts.EmpID = rs.EmpID 
      )
SELECT  A.[empID],
/*      ... And the rest of your query as is.
        ... Just substitute tuitionSubmissions with UniqueSubs.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want by adding the last part below to your where clause

```
WHERE
   (B.[EmpID]= COALESCE(@ntid, B.[EmpID]) OR
            B.[SupEmpID]= COALESCE(@supervisor, B.[SupEmpID]) OR
            C.[SupEmpID]= COALESCE(@manager, C.[SupEmpID]) OR
            A.[EmpID]= COALESCE(@empName, C.[EmpID]) OR
            B.[GeoLocationDesc]= COALESCE(@theLocation, B.[GeoLocationDesc]) OR
            B.[SiloDesc]= COALESCE(@department, B.[SiloDesc]))
    AND A.[id] IN
      (SELECT MAX(AMax.id)
       FROM tuitionSubmissions AS AMax
       GROUP BY AMax.empID)
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get both records where  the empID is the same

Comment: You need () around your OR statements.

Comment: Added them, still pulls both records from tuitionSubmissions where both records have the same empID

Comment: http://oi60.tinypic.com/255jn1k.jpg  - Both of those records are showing up on my page with that query being ran.

Comment: Then you have duplicate empNo records in one of the other tables.